# gsap says e is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap

im trying to use gsap 3.6.1 for my Animation.
After i load the Page, it give me that error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: e is undefined
    oa https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.6.1/gsap.min.js:10
    Tween https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.6.1/gsap.min.js:10
    to https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.6.1/gsap.min.js:10
    <anonymous> http://127.0.0.1:5500/js/app.js:58
    jQuery 13

And JQuery says:
jQuery.Deferred exception: e is undefined oa@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.6.1/gsap.min.js:10:2535
Tween@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.6.1/gsap.min.js:10:32685
to@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.6.1/gsap.min.js:10:38025
@http://127.0.0.1:5500/js/app.js:58:10
mightThrow@https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js:3557:29
resolve/</process<@https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js:3625:12
setTimeout handler*resolve/<@https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js:3663:16
fire@https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js:3291:31
fireWith@https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js:3421:7
fire@https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js:3429:10
fire@https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js:3291:31
fireWith@https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js:3421:7
ready@https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js:3901:13
completed@https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js:3911:9
EventListener.handleEvent*@https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js:3927:11
@https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js:36:10
@https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js:40:4
 undefined
```

My Code looks like this:

```
gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);
gsap.to({
    scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: "#first",
        start: "top center",
        pin: true,
        scrub: true,
        markers: true
    },
    opacity: 0,
    transform: "scale(5)"
});
```

Im using gsap 3.6.1 with the ScrollTrigger Plugin.
Scripttags are these:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.6.1/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.6.1/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>
```

I am very confused by this Error...

EDIT:
If i use the non minified Lib the error is still there!
Here is the Error from the non minified Version:

```
Uncaught TypeError: e is undefined
oa http://127.0.0.1:5500/js/lib/gsap.js:156
Tween http://127.0.0.1:5500/js/lib/gsap.js:1065
to http://127.0.0.1:5500/js/lib/gsap.js:1170
<anonymous> http://127.0.0.1:5500/js/app.js:58
jQuery 13
```

Comment: It's virtually impossible to diagnose an error that complains about a minified variable. Can you load the non-minified library?

Comment: Show the error from the non minified version so we can see the line number the where error happens.

Comment: Please make a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).